# Birth of a universe vs birth of an universe

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, phonology, phonetics

Which is the correct usage from the following two sentences?

1. Birth of a universe
2. Birth of an universe

Comment: It's _establishment of A university_, not _AN university_. Likewise here.

Comment: @user405662 Ok, but why?

Comment: @Araucaria-Not here any more  It's the _sound_ of the vowel (and not the vowel itself) that decides if one should use _a_ or _an_. For this reason, it's _a European_ and _an hotel_.(though _a hotel_ isn't wrong either).

Comment: @Michael Harvey: I don't think it's implicit in my previous comment that _any_ word starting with the letter *h* takes _an_. And of course, it is _a hat_ and _a house_.

Comment: It's the *pronunciation* of the following word that counts. So someone who "drops their aitches" would say "I am buying an 'at to wear in an 'ouse."

Comment: Doesn't Universe start with a U sound. AEIOU = an, right?

Comment: @PriteshDesai: It does, but *universe* is pronounced ***you**niverse*. The first sound—the y—is a consonant, not a vowel.

Comment: Phonetically speaking, in the words 'universe', 'European', 'university' ... etc... the first syllables ('u' or 'Eu') are pronounced [ ju: ]. So,  the first sound which is pronounced is [ j ]. It is a consonant sound. This is the reason why you must use the article 'a'. Same thing with the word 'yacht', for ex. :  the first sound you hear in 'yacht' is [ j ]. In consequence, the question you should ask yourself before deciding between 'a' or 'an' is: what is the FIRST sound I can hear? A vowel sound (e.g. [ u: ] , [ a: ], [ æ ] ... etc...) or a consonant sound [ j ], [ h ] ..etc.. ] ?

Comment: I feel cheated. AEIO yoU?

Comment: I think you should have a look at a list of phonetic symbols. Most dictionaries have one. I'm prettty sure it will help you make a difference between letters and sounds.

Comment: From the way he writes, I don't think he doesn't know the answer to his own question.